# Edit view saving twice

Tags: python, django

```
def edit(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    edit_form = EditPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if edit_form.is_valid():
        instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save(update_fields=['content'])
```

This is my edit view to update a `Post` (it only updates the `content` field). However what happens is the `Post` saves twice and therefore it shows up twice in my queryset. I have 2 saves in the view code which is the problem, but how else would I perform the edit here?

Full view:

```
def edit(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    edit_form = EditPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if edit_form.is_valid():
        instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save(update_fields=['content'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print(edit_form.errors)
        edit_form = PostForm(instance=post)
    context = {
        'edit_form': edit_form,
        'form_post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

sql:

```
[11/Mar/2017 13:11:57] "GET /post/edit/192/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7394
[11/Mar/2017 13:12:08] "POST /post/edit/192/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Mar/2017 13:12:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Mar/2017 13:12:08] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20044
```

**EDIT**

views

```
def edit(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    print('CAT:', post.category)
    edit_form = EditPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if edit_form.is_valid():
        print('Edit valid')
        instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save(update_fields=['content'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print('Errors:', edit_form.errors)
        print('Non-field Errors:', edit_form.non_field_errors)
        edit_form = PostForm(instance=post)
    context = {
        'edit_form': edit_form,
        'form_post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

terminal output when I edit a post:

```
CAT: 1
Errors: 
Non-field Errors: <bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <EditPostForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(content)>>
[23/May/2017 04:37:22] "GET /post/edit/37/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7430
CAT: 1
Edit valid
```

every time a Post is created:

```
def create_post_score(sender, **kwargs):
    score = PostScore.objects.create(post=kwargs['instance'])
    print(score.upvotes)

post_save.connect(create_post_score, sender=Post)
```

Comment: Going through some of my old answers, I came across this one. Is it sorted out now?

Comment: Still not sorted, however I've added new code in my edit which shows the views and terminal output when I edit a post. Printing `CAT` twice or the non-field error is possibly the cause but i'm not sure.

Comment: There isn't anything here that shows the model being saved twice.

Comment: Every time a post is created is also calls `create_post_score` to create a `PostScore` for keeping track of the votes on a post (added in my edit). Any idea if this is related or no?

Comment: What do you mean by that? `create_post_score()` is just above `edit()`. They're in the same views.py file along with `post()`.

Comment: in the same views file, `from django.db.models.signals import post_save`

Comment: I am so sorry. I missed the signal

Comment: hang on a second why are you calling save on the form and also on the object? YOu need only one

Comment: if i remove `instance.save(update_fields=['content'])`, then it doesn't edit the post. If I change it to only `edit_form.save(update_fields=['content'])` then `update_fields` gets an `unexpected argument` error.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the [save method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L431) it clearly shows there isn't an sql command being executed when `commit = False`. The actual database call happens in your next line when you do `instance.save`

If you are seeing two updates happening, it can possibly be because the form is being submitted twice. This can safely be ignored because many RDBMS are smart enough not to update unchanged data. However even that can be avoided by using the standard django pattern of redirect after form handling

```
instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)
instance.save(update_fields=['content'])
return HttpResponseRediret('/success_url/')
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the full view (already using `HttpResponseRedirect`), added in edit

Comment: add the sql that you said appeared in the logs as well please. (but really it can be ignored)

Comment: Ok i added the sql but for some reason it's working now. If I have any problems i'll come back here, thanks.

Comment: Using the exact same code you're using and it's saving twice. It seems the first `instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)` saves it and the next line saves it again. Any idea how to save it only once?

Comment: nopes, commit=False ensures that you are saving it only once so the problem is definitely somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify request.method in the view, if not the form is submitted in the get request also.
Since, the form already contains the "post" instance, form is already valid and it is saved.

Edit your view like this,

```
def edit(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    #If it is a POST request do the thing below.
    if request.method == "POST":
        edit_form = EditPostForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            form.instance.save(update_fields=['content'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        edit_form = EditPostForm(instance=post)
    context = {
            'edit_form': edit_form,
            'form_post': post
            }
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

Comment: Had to adjust the `context` because it's referenced before assignment, but it's still saving twice.

Comment: Still saving twice.

Comment: Still saving post twice or creating postscore which one is it?

Comment: Well every time a new `Post` is created, it creates a new `PostScore` (shown in my edit). So the current situation is `edit()` creating a new `Post` (along with a new `PostScore` to go with it) on top of the already existing `Post` (and `PostScore`).